# BDD specflow test reports with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, specflow, nunit-3.0, nunit-2.6

I am trying to integrate donut type report using specflow and NUnit2.64(I have tried with Nunit3 as well) using Jenkins. Has anyone tried that I google it but can't find much detail?

I have done the following configuration in my Jenkins.

```
MSBuild Version : MSBuild
MSBuild Build File: Myproject.sln
```

Execute Windows batch command

```
Command: D:\myprojectPath\bin\nunit3-console D:\projectPath\bin\Debug\RESTAPITest.dll --result=TestResult.xml

D:\Reports\specflow.exe nunitexecution report D:\myProjectPath\projName.csproj /out:MyTestResults.html
```

Publish Nunit test result report

```
Test report XMLs: TestResult.xml
```

The report I am getting is like this. But my TestResult.xml shows all the steps of scenario. Don't know what I am missing and I wanted to show reports in donut kind of form.

[image]

Comment: Which SpecFlow version are you using?
Be aware, that SpecFlow has not yet full support for the NUnit3 test result output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output the report in the correct format when using NUnit3 (see [Specflow documentation](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting#nunit-3)) as Specflow doesn't support NUnit3 fully at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using allure.  I have integrated allure onto our specflow projects which creates pretty good reports.

Checkout this useful post which will explain you on how to configure your jenkins with allure.  Basic idea is to still run your tests using VSTEst and using the trx file that is generated, you could create allure reports by pointing to the TestResults/*.trx path.
https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/424